# Pyqtgraph not plotting curves - not clearing viewbox

Tags: pyqt5, pyqtgraph

**Pyqtgraph not showing curves on the plot**

I'm trying to plot data but with two Y-axes. Everything is showing but the curves representing the data. I have added some print statements to check if the curves are even added to the plot and they are. They are just not visible. What would be the problem?
Image of the plot: [plot_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FuaHJ.png)

UPDATE: I have placed curve 1,3,4 to plotItem, and curve2 to viewbox and now it is working. But now I have a problem of clearing the ViewBox - it is not working.

I have tried, removing the items and readding, but they are not re-added. The curve is completely deleted.

My goal is to have a graph showing graph readings for multiple pots. but now i see light intensity of every pot - on every graph.
[Multiple light intensity curves on one graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OyuM4.png)

My code:

```
  def sensor_graph(self, pot_id):

    pot_id = self.sync_pot.property("id")
    print(pot_id)

    self.plot_widget.clear()

    p = self.plot_widget.plotItem
   
    self.plot_widget.getPlotItem().setContentsMargins(0, 10, 0, 10)

    p.clear()
    p.clearPlots()
    p.vb.clear()

    v2 = pg.ViewBox()
    
    
    v2.clear()
    p.getViewBox().removeItem(v2)
    p.scene().addItem(v2)

                
    p.setTitle("Sensor readings")

    p.getAxis('left').linkToView(p.vb)
    p.getAxis('right').linkToView(v2)
    x_axis = pg.DateAxisItem(orientation='bottom')
    p.setAxisItems({'bottom': x_axis})

    v2.setXLink(p)


    with Session(bind=db_engine) as local_session:
        readings = local_session.query(SensorReadings).filter(SensorReadings.pot_id == pot_id).all()
        for reading in readings:
            print(f"Reading - Timestamp: {reading.datetime}, Temperature: {reading.temperature_celsius}, Light Intensity: {reading.light_intensity_lux}, Soil Moisture: {reading.soil_moisture}, Soil pH: {reading.soil_ph}")

    x_data = [reading.datetime.timestamp() for reading in readings]
    y1_data = [reading.temperature_celsius for reading in readings]
    y2_data = [reading.light_intensity_lux for reading in readings]
    y3_data = [reading.soil_moisture for reading in readings]
    y4_data = [reading.soil_ph for reading in readings]

    p.clear()
    p.clearPlots()
    p.vb.clear()
    v2.clear()

    pen1 = pg.mkPen(color='#E07D54')
    pen2 = pg.mkPen(color='#DB9600')
    pen3 = pg.mkPen(color='#5E9299')
    pen4 = pg.mkPen(color='#523D35')

    curve1 = pg.PlotCurveItem(x_data, y1_data, pen=pen1, name='Temperature')
    curve2 = pg.PlotCurveItem(x_data, y2_data, pen=pen2, name='Light Intensity')
    curve3 = pg.PlotCurveItem(x_data, y3_data, pen=pen3, name='Soil Moisture')
    curve4 = pg.PlotCurveItem(x_data, y4_data, pen=pen4, name='Soil pH')
   
    p.addItem(curve1)
    p.addItem(curve3)
    p.addItem(curve4)
    v2.addItem(curve2)
    

    self.plot_widget.setLabel('left', '<span style="color:#E07D54">Temperature(°C),</span> <span style="color:#5E9299">Soil Moisture,</span> <span style="color:#523D35">Soil pH</span>')
    self.plot_widget.setLabel('right', '<span style="color:#DB9600">Light Intensity (LUX)</span>')
    self.plot_widget.setLabel('bottom', 'Time')

    v2.setGeometry(p.vb.sceneBoundingRect())

    v2.linkedViewChanged(p.vb, v2.XAxis)

    p.vb.sigResized.connect(lambda: v2.setGeometry(p.vb.sceneBoundingRect()))

    self.plot_widget.update()
```

Comment: Seems correct, have you tried: 
 1. verifying **data** format/validValues 
 2. check **y-axis ranges** (if too small, the curves may not be visible, try manually setting each `p.setRange(yRange=(min_value, max_value))`)
 3. confirm **visibility** and has correct **size** (`self.plot_widget`)
 4. verify no **overlap** of UI elements hiding them
 5. check **colour** is visible against background

Comment: Thank you got your answer. I have partially fixed the problem, but ofcourse now i have another problem :)